# eslint :'isResetProperty' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have used following code but getting the above eslint error.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.isResetProperty) {
          this.setState({ empName: defaultEmpName });
          this.setState({ empAddress: defaultEmpAddress });
          this.props.resetPage(false);
        }
      }
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^3.18.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
}
```

How can I resolve the error : **[eslint] 'isResetProperty' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)** .Please assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare type for `isResetProperty` property. [About PropTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). [About this rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md).

**Full Example**

```
// index.js
import { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class Cmp extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    isResetProperty: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.isResetProperty) {
      this.setState({
        reset: nextProps.isResetProperty,
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "eslint": "3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.5.4"
  }
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "semi": [2, "never"]
  }
}
```

`>$ yarn run lint`

> yarn run v0.24.6
>   $ eslint .
>   Done in 1.32s.

Comment: It wont work because in above code we are using nextProps.isResetProperty, your code will work if it is use like this.props.isResetProperty.

Comment: @jack123 Have you actually tried it? I don't know which eslint version you have. Mine works like a charm.

Comment: I am using "eslint": "^3.18.0",

Comment: after updating to new version as you use above eslint error not coming, but  static propTypes = {
    isResetProperty: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  } this one no need to define in this scenario. It will automatically resolve by new version.

Comment: @jack123 That's kinda unexpected. If I remove `static propTypes` definition from the class I get "
  6:19  error  'isResetProperty' is missing in props validation  react/prop-type" As it supposed to be.

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class YourComponentName extends React.Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.isResetProperty) {
      this.setState({ empName: defaultEmpName });
      this.setState({ empAddress: defaultEmpAddress });
      this.props.resetPage(false);
    }
  }
};

YourComponentName.propTypes = {
  isResetProperty: PropTypes.<type-of-isResetProperty>
}
```

Comment: It wont work because in above code we are using nextProps.isResetProperty, your code will work if it is use like this.props.isResetProperty.